# directing Outputstreams into the System.Out Stream

Tags: java, io, stream

I'm trying to use a PrintStream thats writes Strings into another OutputStream(in this case, System.out)

```
public void druckeDaten(OutputStream os){

    String t = "ID = " + getID() + " \"" + getTitel() + "\" "
            + "von " + interpreter + " aus " + getJahr()
            + " Spieldauer: " + dauer + " sek.";

    PrintStream pw = new PrintStream(os);
    pw.printf(t);
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
}
```

if I call the method druckeDaten in a loop, the console prints only one line

```
 Collections.sort(liste);
//liste is a LinkedList containing the Objects that I want to use the druckeDaten on
        for(Medium m : liste)
            m.druckeDaten(System.out);
```

where did I go wrong?

Comment: You are closing the stream in your method druckeDaten.

Answer (score 0):

You closed your `PrintStream` which will cascade the `close()` to the underlying stream. You closed `System.out` (which is also a `PrintStream`, so it's not necessary to wrap it).

Comment: Thank you very much